# Creating a VSIX probject for an asp.net template app

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vsix

I have built an asp.net application project that I want to deploy as a VSIX project so other can install it and build asp.net applications from a template.

I have my solution, and in the solution is my ASP.Net application project and my VSIX project.

In the VSIX project I've created the ProjectTemplate\CSharp\Web\1033 directory.

What I want to do is if I build the solution, my web application outputs to the .zip file (all source code for the template) and places in the 1033 directory, then the extension project builds, and all I have to do is distribute the VISX project output.

Most online samples are not complete.  Anyone have any good resources to walk through this process?

Answer (score 2):

Have you taken a look at this post? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/03/04/creating-and-sharing-project-item-templates.aspx

It should walk you through the process of setting your projects up correctly to distribute templates via VSIX.

Comment: This looks really promising.  If I have a web application project built, how can I go about somehow linking these files instead of copying them into the template project, so if I add or change files in my template web app, the changes automatically feed into the template project?